# How can I adjust the (yellow line) length of the light in Blender?

Tags: 3d-view, light

How can I adjust the (yellow line) length of the light in Blender? Can we make it shorter? 
I think yellow lines that from the lamps are too long when comparing to the object scene. 
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are using an *Area* light.

For *area* and *spot* type lights, the line visualizes the *Custom Distance > Distance*, regard of wether *Custom Distance* is active. You can change it with the Distance property.

[image: distance]

If you would like to remove the yellow tracking blob *"Look At"*, uncheck *Look At* in the viewports Gizmo settings.

[image: blob]

If you are using cycles (or another render engine), this *Distance* propetry is not accessible, although it is represented in the viewport. Briefly switch to the *EEVEE* render engine, change the *distance* value until the viewport looks good, the switch back to your actual render engine.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answers :) @Leander
I've looked into my Blender window at light section but I cannot find the "Custom Distance" Could you please advise?  https://imgur.com/a/ztQxVOR

Comment: @PANAS I added a paragraph. Does this solve your problem? In your question, the value is visible in the screenshot.

Comment: Yeah! I got it! and it works :) Again, thank you so much. This is very helpful. 
P.s. I'm very new to Blender and this is my new knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea, why, but the setting for spotlights is just not there in Blender 3.0 beta:

[image]

I solved the issue by opening Python console, selecting one of my spot lights and typing  `C.object.data.`followed by <kbd>tab</kbd> for autocomplete:

[image]

I looked through all the properties and found one called "cutoff_distance" and changed it with command `C.object.data.cutoff_distance = 0.1` and it worked.

"cutoff_distance" sounds a little scary - like it's going to cut the light off at that distance, but when rendering with Cycles, the light seems to be OK and it's only that line in the viewport that gets shortened.

Hope this might help someone with same issue.